# Holding on ImageView to change InputType of TextView - Android

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I have EditText with InputType of password and one ImageView like a button. So I want when user hold his finger on that image, InputType of EditText to become normal text, and when user remove finger, InputType again to be password. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener {
   public onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
       //set edittext to normal
    }
    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
    {
     // set edittext to password
    }
    return true;                         
   }
});
```

The above code should work, it might need a little tweaking - I can't test it at the moment. Should give you a good idea on how to handle it.

Comment: I got error on code: event == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -->
Incompatible operand types MotionEvent and int

Comment: Try event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN

Answer (score 1):

You can do a [setOnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29) on the `Image` and inside you can call the [setInputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29) of the `EditText`. Just report to this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) to see wich `setInputType` parameter suits you the most.

Comment: This was my first understanding of the question but I think he is asking for a touch down and touch up event.

Comment: @JamieB Oh yeah, you're correct. I will change that.